# Strategy for S3.getSignedUrl asynchronous call for large number of objects?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to display a large amount (a few thousand) images from S3 to a user.

Since I'm using EC2 Instance credentials, I must call `getSignedUrl` asynchronously.

Currently, I have 2 solutions, but they offer about the same performance.

1. I create a `new Promise` for each `getSignedUrl` call.
2. I use an atomic counter to keep track of the async callbacks and use `setInterval` to periodically check the counter until it is done.

Both these methods have no noticeable performance differences (in Node 6.9.1), taking around 15 seconds to complete about 8k `getSignedUrl` calls.

I wonder if there's a better way to solve this? Is there a way to call `getSignedUrl` synchronously (and quickly) with EC2 instance profile credentials? Or get a single signing key that can sign all of my images?

Comment: Have you benchmarked using getSignedUrl with static credentials? There may be no difference: ~2 ms to generate a signed URL seems like it could be all CPU time -- I would hope the SDK caches the role credentials, since they include an expiration timestamp and are easily cached -- but assuming Signature V4 you're presumably doing 5 iterations of HMAC-SHA-256 for each URL, 4 of which are generating the ((((date)+region)+service)+signing) keys and are redundant after the first of many sequential signed URLs... and the SDK may or may not not be clever enough to optimize that redundant work away.

Comment: CloudFront signed URLs support wildcards, but S3 does not.  Have you considered that approach?